# WinJS: x-ms-webview.addWebAllowedObject method example

Tags: win-universal-app, winjs

Could anyone provide me some sample code on how to use [addWebAllowedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn926632.aspx) in UWP javascript base app?
I tried to use

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function publish(envelope) {
        console.log("publish to native js");
    }

    WinJS.Namespace.define("messageBus", {
        publish: publish

    });
})();

webview.addWebAllowedObject("MessageBus", messageBus);
```

But I got the error:

```
0x80004002 - JavaScript runtime error: No such interface supported
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me with it.

Comment: The webview in your caode is WebView, iframe or x-ms-webview?

Comment: it's x-ms-webview, thanks